# CSS/jQuery image grid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, masonry

I have read many threads about image grid layouts using jQuery or even sole CSS, but mine is a little bit different to what I have read as they are mainly using columns with differing widths.

I am also purposely not pasting any code at this point due to the fact that I have tried various different methods that my code seems no longer 'nice'.

As you can see from this page: http://tinyurl.com/poxn4un - what I am trying to acheive is the images (in Our Work section) laid out how they are now but with the bottom two slotting nicely between the two edge images.

I have tried masonry with no success and also tried flexbox which is what is it in use at this point.  Any help would be appreciated as this is something I wish to learn for other projects.

Thanks, Adrian

Comment: I don't think standard CSS will be able to achieve this for you. You will have to explicitly tell the blocks where to go using absolute positions or a tool like masonry. If you know the exact layout, you should be able to achieve it with absolute positions. And if it has to scale, then use percentages for your absolute positions and widths.

Comment: I wanted to avoid absolute positioning in case the client then wanted to change the images to images of different dimensions, however I think I am probably best using absolute positioned divs and adding the images as centered background images so if other images were uploaded, the background image would still 'cover'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure masonry could do that but you might have to use a dummy transparent image.

Comment: Yes, I see that you would want to constrain either by limited what they upload or by using 'cover' as you've done. Either way, the absolute pos approach should work?.. You might want to get the system to know which images are landscape and which are portrait so they can be arranged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flex-box combination layout for this.

Here's an example:

## <kbd>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r7jq74qg/)</kbd>

And here's the CSS and HTML powering it:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bricks {
    display: flex;
    height: 450px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.bricks > * {
    border: solid 1px #222;
}
.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 220px;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/220x450/075883);
}
.center-contain {
    flex: 0 0 402px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/200x225);
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    height: 225px;
}
.center.m {
    width: 200px;
}
.center.lg {
    width: 300px;
}
.center.sm {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bricks'>
    <div class='sidebar sidebar-left'></div>
    <div class='center-contain'>
        <div class='center sm'></div>
        <div class='center lg'></div>
        <div class='center m'></div>
        <div class='center m'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar sidebar-right'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your answer and the demo looks great, only problem is on the site the center images are different sizes also. Top row first image is larger width than 2nd, and bottom row 2nd image is wider than first. Could a few extra classes sort this?

Comment: Since it's just a `display: inline-block` in the center, as long as they fit in the max-width of the overall container it should just be as easy as putting them in the `center-contain` div.

Comment: @Adrian – Updated to illustrate.